# The hidden 'lat' and 'lng' fields were not removed and so my script was still searching for the lat and lng results from the incorrect geolocation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where the user can input their address into the 'zipcode' field. I also have a "detect location" button that geolocates the users address. When they click on this button, their city name and zipcode are echo'd into the 'zipcode' field, and the latitude and longitude are passed to two dynamically created hidden input fields. I also have the Places API on the page.

The code that echos the address and zipcode, and creates the hidden fields, is as follows:

```
if (results[1]) {
    split1 = results[1].formatted_address.split(', ');
    // echo the geolocation address into the 'zipcode' input field
    document.getElementById('zipcode').value = split1[1] + ', ' + split1[2]; // city name and postcode
    // if hidden lat and lng fields are present from Places API, remove them
    $(".storelocator_body form").find("input.geomtery").remove();
    // produce new hidden fields with the new lat and lng values
    $(".storelocator_body form").append("<input type='hidden' class='geomtery' name='lat' value='" + lat + "'>");
    $(".storelocator_body form").append("<input type='hidden' class='geomtery' name='lng' value='" + lng + "'>");
} else {
    alert("No results found");
}
```

The problem I was having is that at times, the geolocation gave spurious results, especially if I'm searching from a desktop without a wireless card. When I went to manually change the 'zipcode' input field to the correct address, the hidden 'lat' and 'lng' fields were not removed and so my script was still searching for the lat and lng results from the incorrect geolocation.

The solution I came up with is as follows:

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName("geomtery")){
    $("#zipcode").on("input",function(e){
        $(".storelocator_body form").find("input.geomtery").remove();
    });
}
```

my line of thinking is that if the user starts to type or even paste a new address into the 'zipcode' input field, and there are hidden 'lat' and 'lng' fields already present, then these get removed.

What do you think? Have I done this the best possible way? I'm new to coding and would love some feedback.
Many thanks.

Comment: validate the length of  document.getElementById('zipcode').value and return it to appropriate lat and long or show some proper page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why make it hard for yourself? Instead of doing DOM insertion everytime, you could simply detect whether the fields exist (or even better, include them in the HTML directly), and change their value.

```
 // here your Places code, field as optional parameter (to retrieve from zipcode afterwards)  
function placesAPIcall(field) { [...] return { lat: 'value', long: 'value'}}
// on page load
function initPlaces() {
   var result = placesAPIcall(), lat = result.lat, lng = result.lng;
   if (!$('.geomtery[name=lat]').length)
      $('.storelocator_body form').append('<input type="hidden" class="geomtery" name="lat" value="' + lat + '">');
   if (!$('.geomtery[name=lng]').length)
      $('.storelocator_body form').append('<input type="hidden" class="geomtery" name="lng" value="' + lng + '">');
}
// everytime #zipcode loses focus, value updates
function updateLatLong() { 
   var result = placesAPIcall($('#zipcode')), lat = result.lat, lng = result.lng;
   $('.geomtery[name=lat]').val(lat); // set the value
   $('.geomtery[name=lng]').val(lng); // set the value

});
$('#zipcode').on({'change': updateLatLong, 'load': initPlaces});
```

Some tips:

- Choose between single (`"`) and double (`'`) quotation marks and stay consistent. 
  Personally I always use `"` for HTML and `'` for JS.
- As far as I know, there is no `input` event in jQuery, use `change` or `keyup` or form `submit` instead.
- You sent `e` (event) as parameter in your function: you should only include the parameters you need (none, in this case), else it might confuse others who read your code.
- Consistent coding style: If you choose to use jQuery, there is no point in using native JS functions like `document.getElementsByClassName` as it doesn't work in IE8- and jQuery's simpler class selector `$('.class')`, by contrast, does.
- `geomtery` is a typo for geometry?

Comment: you've given me a few excellent tips there @Tyblitz so thanks for that! Making the code more efficient vis-a-vis fewer DOM insertions makes absolute sense. I have edited my code now and I'm much happier with it, so thanks for that. many very good points!